# values-v23.xml error.Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, xml

I am getting these error in values-v23.xml:

Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

My build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "example.transportmanagement"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
   }
```

I want to compile at API 21. I read many question but it was told to change the sdkversion to 23. How can I solve this error with API 21

Manifest.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.transportmanagement"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/im4"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.SignUp"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.SignUp" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.Login" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.SelectAddress"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.SelectAddress" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.Driver"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.Driver" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.FindBus"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.FindBus" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.MapsActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="example.transportmanagement.DriverMaps"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.transportmanagement.DriverMaps" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


    </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: Before you run into a problem with multidex hitting the 65K method limit, please read this. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile for API 21 why do you have an file value v23 in your project?

If you use  Valuev 23 android studio understand that you want a API 23 application.

So try to remove this file or rename it with v21. It should work

Comment: Removed the values v23.xml file from AndroidStudioProjects\TransportManagement\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\ ... But when I rebuild the project , it generates again and shows the same error.

Comment: Can you add the AndroidManifest and a picture of the Android Studio configuration build?

Comment: I have added my manifest detail. You told to share picture of configuration. I couldn't get that. how to get detail of of configuration so that I can share it with you.Being new to this, I have less idea about all these. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can compile with SDK and Build tools 23 and still target and run code on API 17..21

Comment: Is there any other alternative by which I can compile at 21 itself.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do so?

Comment: If I compile at 23 and target it at 21, will I need to handle run time permission too? as 23 requires that. It may be silly to ask but I am a fresher in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you only are asked permissions on devices with API 23. You aren't targeting those devices, though, you are only compiling code so you can include those missing resources. My personal test device is API 21 and I compile with the latest SDK, and it runs fine, if that makes you feel any better

Comment: thank you. I will update my sdk and will try to do so. will drop a comment in case I stuck again.